# Amazon Alexa: Is it possible to get the response as JSON

Tags: android, alexa-voice-service

I am new to Alexa development and I found a sample library in GitHub.

https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

It get your voice command and response from amazon in Voice. Is there away to get the text response e.g JSON format so I can get the response and take an appropriate action

ie. If asking a weather forecast, i would have a response as text so I can show up on a screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Currently you will only get the response as in audio format. There was some article about Amazon Alexa where selected developers will get access to the APIs to display cards in their applications.

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/935a202f-d236-4492-866e-a8419d952fca/display-cards-for-alexa-a-new-complementary-feature-for-screen-based-products

But as far as your question goes Amazon doesnt return the reponse in the text format.

Best Regds